# SELECT @@ROWCOUNT in SSMS (2014,2016)

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Why this code gives `1` in new query window of SSMS?

```
select @@ROWCOUNT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSMS issues several queries after it creates a connection.   You can see this using SQL Server Profiler

on my system,

```
select @@spid;
select SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel');
```

is the last query executed.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new connection, your SSMS window automatically sets a number of session variables for you.

Sample trace of a new session being created:

```
select @@spid;
select SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel');
```

As a test you can execute the following statement, and confirm that the result will always be `1`.

```
select @@spid;
select SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel');

select @@ROWCOUNT
```